# Nautilus "Scripts" menu option removes percent sign from filename

Tags: 16.04, nautilus

Executing the following script from the Nautilus "Scripts" right-click menu option with a filename that contains a percent sign removes the percent sign and the next character from the filename. E.g., if the file is called **uvw10%xyz**, the script will print **uvw10yz** to the file abc.txt.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "$1" >> abc.txt
```

Any character, even a space, can follow the percent sign and the problem remains. And I realize it works from the terminal; that's not the question. The point is that it doesn't work when run as a Nautilus script.

What's going on here? How can I fix it?

Apparently, the correct filenames can be printed like this:

```
while read line; do
    [ "$line" ] && echo "$line"
done <<< "$NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS" > abc.txt
```

But I would still like to know what's happening with the precent sign in the original code.

Answer (score 0):

I think **uvw10%xyz** has **%x** in it.
So its considered as specifier i guess, Although it works fine from terminal.
Try the below code

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $1 >> abc.txt
```

You can also try this:

```
filepath=$NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS then name=${filepath##*/} then name=${name% then } then printf %s "$name"> abc.txt
```

Comment: In what sense is it a "specifier"? I realize it works from the terminal; that's not the question. It doesn't matter what letter, or even a space, is after the %. Your first code snippet is useless since it compresses spaces. Your afterthought might be useful. I asked why it was happening, though. Does anyone have an answer that isn't a guess? Is it a bug?